# selecting which pairwise comparisons to run in R, and adjusting

Tags: r

Let us assume that I am running a 2 (Gender) x 3 (Treatment) ANOVA, similar to what is described here:

http://rtutorialseries.blogspot.com/2011/02/r-tutorial-series-two-way-anova-with.html

I find a significant interaction effect, and I want to explore this interaction effect using pairwise comparisons. However, if I use the pairwise.t.test function in R then it will run t-tests for every possible permutation of the interaction. I, however, only want to investigate whether stress level is different for males vs females at each level of the Treatment factor; that is, I only want to conduct 3 pairwise comparisons. Furthermore, I want to adjust the p-values for those 3 comparisons using FDR correction.

Is there a way to select which comparisons are conducted using the pairwise.t.test function in R?

Comment: By declaring a new `factor` with only 3 levels?

Comment: see the `multcomp` package for a flexible framework.